# How does Gson.fromJson method succeeded to parse a Json string although TypeToken isn't suit to parsed String?

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, gson

I have a code that I can't understand why it isn't throwing a *run time exception*.
Here is a *Json* String that I'm trying to convert to Map<String, Any>, **but** some of the keys **are from Int type and not a String**.
The code:

```
    val json = """{1: "Kotlin Tutorial", "2": "bezkoder", "3" : ["Kotlin","Basic"]}"""
    val gson = Gson()

    var tutorialMap: Map<Int, Any> = gson.fromJson(json, object : TypeToken<Map<Int, Any>>() {}.type)
    tutorialMap.forEach { Log.e("dadffas",it.toString()) }
```

As you can see *keys: 1,3* are from **Int** type. What happen here? some kind of boxing?
In addition if I declare the **TypeToken** as Map<Int,Any> code is still being compiled? Again kind of boxing (behind the scene *String.toInt* method is running)?

Comment: 1) JSON supports neither _int_ nor _numeric_ keys: valid JSON documents can only contain string keys, period. 2) Gson is pretty lenient to malformed JSON documents and allows reading numeric keys as if they were strings. https://github.com/google/gson/blob/ceae88bd6667f4263bbe02e6b3710b8a683906a2/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.java#L775

Comment: @fluffy, i entered to the link and didn't understand what is going there :( In addition i wrote: * In addition if I declare the TypeToken as Map<Int,Any> code is still being compiled? Again kind of boxing (behind the scene String.toInt method is running)?* Is it true?

Comment: It is compiled because the `fromJson` method overload you're using accepts an instance of `Type`, and not `TypeToken` where it could infer the result type from: both _left_ type and _right_ type are unrelated in such a scenario. It is not a "kind of boxing" (and I do believe there is nothing like `String.toInt` behind the scenes, since object property names are always read as strings even if they look like numbers).

Comment: Therefore, `it.key.javaClass` will _always_ return `java.lang.String`. And the reason of it does not fail at runtime is that you are not dereferencing the key as an `Int` that would throw a class-cast exception in runtime.

Comment: I have edited the post (change the *tutorialMap* variable type). You said that it.key.javaClass will always return j*ava.lang.String* but the following assignment is valid: var vv: Class<Int> = it.key.javaClass and var vv: Class<String> = it.key.javaClass isn't valid

Comment: Again, the compiler cannot infer the real types from the `fromJson` method. What you've just shown is what it _can_ analyze at compile time. Next, if you get an entry from `tutorialMap` and take its key -- it will throw a runtime error.

Comment: But look at my comments. i'm taking a key and everything ok. The following code:  var vv: Class<*>  = it.key.javaClass
Log.e("abc",vv.name)
prints: **abc:int**

Comment: I seem not to be aware of the coercion Ridcully is talking about, so providing another key-typed map type token would apply the appropriate strategies. I have to look deeper.

Comment: This is where the "magic" happens: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/ceae88bd6667f4263bbe02e6b3710b8a683906a2/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/MapTypeAdapterFactory.java#L186

Comment: Are you talking on:  JsonReaderInternalAccess.INSTANCE.promoteNameToValue(in);
?

Comment: No, take a look at `keyTypeAdapter` -- this is a type adapter that can read keys of types other than strings. I applied a type token with an `Integer` keys map (I do Java, not Kotlin), and Gson seemed to use the Integer type adapter that can read strings as numbers ( https://github.com/google/gson/blob/ceae88bd6667f4263bbe02e6b3710b8a683906a2/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/TypeAdapters.java#L218 ), so this is valid: `System.out.println(new JsonReader(new StringReader("\"1\"")).nextInt())` printing `1`.

Comment: In your example where did you use the IntegerAdapter? i can't understand.. In addition how do you know if it works on key or on value?

Comment: Specifying a type token for integer-keyed map is an implicit way to tell Gson to use the built-in integer type adapter for map keys. Plus, type adapters work in independent context and they do not care if they are keys or values adapters (not strictly true for keys, though). Debug it yourself: put a breakpoint at `nextInt()` in the integer type adapter, deserialize `{1:"a"}`, and run your debugger -- it will end up with `1` even if the key is `"1"`. Also, let's end the discussion in the comments, as suggested by the S.O. rules. Ridcully answered your question anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gson's approach is, to come from the Java/Kotlin side and try to coerce the Json value into the type that is expected on Java side.
So, as the type of the keys of your map is Integer, it tries to coerce what it gets from Json to Integer.

You need to be aware that your whole Json initally is just a string to Gson. It gets tokenized but is still a bunch of strings until in the end Gson sees you want a certain string as an Integer. And it ia clever enough to turn `2` and `"2"` into an integer.

If your json would have a key like `"foo"`, you'd get an exception.

P.S: If you're really interested you can use the debugger and step into the fromJson() method and see exactly how its done.

Comment: i really tried to follow, but the stack is so long,and function call another function that calls another function.. So i really get confused.. I feel like the worst programmer in all world

Comment: Don't worry. One normally does not need to step into library code. Also, your interest in "why does the code work" clearly shows, that you're not a bad programmer.